# Twwdbgrid.PaintOptions.ActiveRecordColor - change background color and font color

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, tdbgrid

I built a project using Delphi 7 with Infopower and 1stClass components.
In one of my forms is use the TwwDBGrid Component.
My Task is when the user selects a specific record, this one to be highlighted with a specific color.
Even though one of TwwDBGrid's properties is the ActiveRecordColor, this provides only limited choices. Moreover, it doesn't let you choose which color to use for background and which for the Font color. (For expamle if one chooses the clGreen color as the ActiveRecordColor he will see that the background will be gree - as he chose - but the font color is white without letting him choose a different color for the Font property of the active record ).

I've found out that one could handle the ActiveRecordColor property by writing code in the "OnEnter" event as well as in the "OnExit" event of the TwwDBGrid instance. However since the event does not provide any attributes with which one could alter - separately - the Font and Background color, i stuck.

Thus i am wondering: is there any workaround to allow me choose myself the Font Color - as well as the Background color - of the current Active Record ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We handle it by using the OnCalcCellColors event.

```
  if Highlight then
  begin
    ABrush.Color := clBlue;
    AFont.Color := clWhite;
  end;
```